# Recaptcha in a Lightbox Causes: TypeError: Recaptcha.widget is null

Tags: javascript, colorbox, recaptcha

I have recaptcha inserted into a form. I am attempting to open the form in a lightbox. When I attempt to I see the following error:

```
TypeError: Recaptcha.widget is null
[Break On This Error]   

...chaTemplates.CleanHtml,f="png");"context"==b&&(d=RecaptchaTemplates.ContextHtml)...

recapt...3f4e.js (line 811)
```

If the form is loaded onto the page it works without issue. It only throws the error when I try to load the form in a lightbox.

I have limited control over reCaptcha because the CMS I use generates all of the code.

How do I load recaptcha in a lightbox without it throwing that error?

Note: I am using Colorbox Lightbox